# ggplot2: plot seconds in %H%M%S format in y axi

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've a column in seconds that need to plot as "%H%M%S".

I've tried using lubridate pkg, but the column results in:

```
loadtime_dfs$avgPageLoadTime <- seconds_to_period(loadtime_df$avgPageLoadTime)


Formal class 'Period' [package "lubridate"]
```

that I can plot but doesn't show any format.

```
loadtime_df <- structure(list(date = structure(c(17766, 17767, 17768, 17769, 
17770, 17771), class = "Date"), pagePath = c("/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/CategoryDisplay?urlRequestType=Base&catalogId=3074457345616676668&categoryId=3074457345616676994&pageView=grid&urlLangId=-24&beginIndex=0&langId=-24&top_category=3074457345616676981&parent_category_rn=3074457345616720192&storeId=10151", 
"/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/CategoryDisplay?urlRequestType=Base&catalogId=3074457345616676668&categoryId=3074457345616676994&pageView=grid&urlLangId=-24&beginIndex=0&langId=-24&top_category=3074457345616676981&parent_category_rn=3074457345616720192&storeId=10151", 
"/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/CategoryDisplay?urlRequestType=Base&catalogId=3074457345616676668&categoryId=3074457345616676994&pageView=grid&urlLangId=-24&beginIndex=0&langId=-24&top_category=3074457345616676981&parent_category_rn=3074457345616720192&storeId=10151", 
"/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/CategoryDisplay?urlRequestType=Base&catalogId=3074457345616676668&categoryId=3074457345616676994&pageView=grid&urlLangId=-24&beginIndex=0&langId=-24&top_category=3074457345616676981&parent_category_rn=3074457345616720192&storeId=10151", 
"/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/CategoryDisplay?urlRequestType=Base&catalogId=3074457345616676668&categoryId=3074457345616676994&pageView=grid&urlLangId=-24&beginIndex=0&langId=-24&top_category=3074457345616676981&parent_category_rn=3074457345616720192&storeId=10151", 
"/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/CategoryDisplay?urlRequestType=Base&catalogId=3074457345616676668&categoryId=3074457345616676994&pageView=grid&urlLangId=-24&beginIndex=0&langId=-24&top_category=3074457345616676981&parent_category_rn=3074457345616720192&storeId=10151"
), pageviews = c(245L, 225L, 194L, 214L, 214L, 213L), pageLoadTime = c(18965L, 
185834L, 31115L, 114561L, 88807L, 0L), avgPageLoadTime = c(6, 
27, 16, 138, 144, 0), bouncerate = c(5.63380281690141, 3.48837209302326, 
5.40540540540541, 7.01754385964912, 0, 5), mes = c("agosto", 
"agosto", "agosto", "agosto", "agosto", "agosto")), .Names = c("date", 
"pagePath", "pageviews", "pageLoadTime", "avgPageLoadTime", "bouncerate", 
"mes"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

This is what I need to plot:

```
ggplot(loadtime_df, aes(date,avgPageLoadTime)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth()
```

But with the Y axis with breaks: "00:01:00", "00:02:00", "00:03:00", "00:04:00", "00:05:00".

Comment: Your `Date` column doesn't have hour, minute or seconds. Can you double check?

Comment: @Tung avgPageLoadTime is in seconds, but not date, is it necessary?

Comment: Omar, if either of the answers sufficiently addresses your question, can you please accept it and close out the question?

Answer (score 3):

You are going to have to provide strings for `ggplot` to assign as labels.

If you read `?scale_y_continuous(labels=...)`, you'll see that `labels=` takes either `waiver()`, `character`, or a `function`. If you want to specify the specific locations and representations, then you'll want to specific both `breaks=` and `labels=`. However, typically you want `ggplot2` to determine where to put the axis labels, so we'll provide a function that takes a value and returns a string.

I'm guessing there's a helper function somewhere to do this, but here's a base-R version. (The origin of the function is unimportant, since we can replace our function with another with likely the same outcome.)

This formatting function cheats a little by temporarily converting the seconds of `avgPageLoadTime` to `POSIXct` and then to a string. Doing it this way means it honors `options("digits.secs")`, if set.

```
fmt_hms <- function(x, digits.secs=NULL) {
  if (!is.null(digits.secs)) {
    oopts <- options(digits.secs = digits.secs)
    on.exit(options(oopts), add=TRUE)
  }
  format(as.POSIXct(x, origin="1970-01-01 00:00:00"), format="%H:%M:%OS", tz="UTC")
}
```

In order to demonstrate this, I'll change one of the values of your data:

```
loadtime_df$avgPageLoadTime[3] <- loadtime_df$avgPageLoadTime[3] + 0.123456
fmt_hms(loadtime_df$avgPageLoadTime)
# [1] "00:00:06" "00:00:27" "00:00:16" "00:02:18" "00:02:24" "00:00:00"
fmt_hms(loadtime_df$avgPageLoadTime, digits.secs=3)
# [1] "00:00:06.000" "00:00:27.000" "00:00:16.123" "00:02:18.000" "00:02:24.000"
# [6] "00:00:00.000"
```

So we can just provide this function:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(loadtime_df, aes(date,avgPageLoadTime)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=fmt_hms)
```

[image: ggplot2 y-axis updated]

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to convert the date values in seconds to a %H%m%s format and then try plotting. I think you need one of the below approaches -

```
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)

# convert seconds to periods 
td <- seconds_to_period(loadtime_df$avgPageLoadTime)
# then apply the required format
avgPageLoadTime_vector <- sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', td@hour, minute(td), 
                                  second(td))


# plotting using %H%m%s we can use them as y-axis ticks
# this will give you the same plot as above but Y-axis is fuzzy
ggplot(loadtime_df, aes(date,avgPageLoadTime)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth() + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = loadtime_df$avgPageLoadTime,
                       labels = avgPageLoadTime_vector)
```

[image]

```
# if you just want to plot with points and not use geom_smooth
# convert the column avgPageLoadTime into %H%m%s date-time format
loadtime_df$avgPageLoadTime <- avgPageLoadTime_vector

# this gives you the right Y-axis values but no smoothing
ggplot(loadtime_df, aes(date,avgPageLoadTime)) + 
  geom_point()
```

[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTSjr.png)